# Rails how to generate entity relationship diagram (ERD)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, diagram

I want to reverse engineer our rails app with an entity relationship diagram that shows all of the tables and their relationships. It looks like this is a snap with the rails-erd gem:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
# gem 'rails-erd'
bundle install
bundle exec rake erd
```

However, the graphviz requirement is not up to date for mac + all of the links for rails erd tools seem sketchy and outdated. How can I visualize my database?

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1 
Rails 5.0.1
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
macOS Sierra 10.12.4
```

Comment: You can also dump the schema as SQL with `rake db:structure:dump` and use any arbitrary SQL visualization software.

Answer (score 5):

Use [railroady](http://railroady.prestonlee.com/) to generate your diagram.

`sudo port install graphviz`

`sudo gem install railroady`

`cd my_rails_project`

Add `"railroady"` in Gemfile.

`rake diagram:all`

`open doc/*.svg`

Voila!

Comment: I am hesitant to sudo anything. I just remembered that I can do `brew install graphviz` instead of downloading it in a browser. Giving it a shot once it's done.

Comment: yeah that's a safer alternative.

Comment: Good call, using sudo to install gems is a really bad idea since the file privileges end up all messed up. Use rbenv or rvm and never use sudo for installing gems.